# One user at a Time

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, login-control, autologin

I am trying to implement that only one user can login with given credentials.

I check this at the time of login with this code :

```
MembershipUser objectUser = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName);
    if (objectUser != null)
    {
        boolIsAlreadyLoggedIn = objectUser.IsOnline;
    }
```

This is working fine. I have problem, when a user checked Remember Me.
Scenario : 
1. If a user logins with Remember Me checked. Close the browser. 
2. Now from another machine or another browser login with same credentials. He can login. 3. But if user login from Browser-1/machine-1 again, he can login, since browser have persistent cookie.

Can anybody suggest me how can I resolve this problem??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the cookie holds a per-login session id. Simply make sure that each user can only be associated with a single session id at a time. Each new login replaces any existing session id for the user with a new one. And of course any request using an expired session id is taken straight to the "not logged in — you may have logged in somewhere else" page.

Comment: I suppose we can handle every Authenticate Request in its Event. But in this event we donot have Session Variable.